# using Dash, Is there a way to repeat same id component in two sections on the page?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using DASH library and I'm trying to use two dropdown filters with the same id so I can filter in any of both and it calls the same callback, and if I change one, the other also need to change. But I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ids should be unique. Duplicate ids in the layout are disallowed (if you're using a recent version of Dash). Dash will throw an exception if you have duplicate ids in the layout.

Instead you should give both dropdowns a unique id and include both components in your callback by their ids.

If you want to change the dropdown value of one dropdown when the other dropdown value changes you could use [`dash.callback_context`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown1",
            options=[
                {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
                {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
                {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
            ],
            value="NYC",
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown2",
            options=[
                {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
                {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
                {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
            ],
            value="NYC",
        ),
        html.Div(id="output"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("dropdown1", "value"),
    Output("dropdown2", "value"),
    Input("dropdown1", "value"),
    Input("dropdown2", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_output(dropdown1_value, dropdown2_value):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    dropdown_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if dropdown_id == "dropdown1":
        dropdown_values = dropdown1_value, dropdown1_value
    elif dropdown_id == "dropdown2":
        dropdown_values = dropdown2_value, dropdown2_value

    return  dropdown_values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

If the `value` property of `dropdown1` changes the callback is triggered and the `value` property of `dropdown2` changes to the value of `dropdown1` and vice versa.

`prevent_initial_callback` is set to `True` so I don't have to check if `dash.callback_context.triggered` is not `None`. You might want to change this depending on your needs.

[image: in sync dropdowns]